# Determine all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(5^m-1,5^n+1)=2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Determine all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\gcd(5^m-1,5^n+1)=2$$

First attempt:

Say $d= (5^m-1,5^n+1)$, then $d|5^m-1$ and $d|5^n+1$ so $d|5^m+5^n$.

If $m=n$ then $d|2$ so $d=2$ since $5^m-1$ and $5^n+1$ are both odd.

If $m>n$ then $d|5^n(5^{m-n}+1)$. Since $5\not|d$ we have by Euclid lemma $d|5^{m-n}+1$ and now what?

---

Second :

We notice if $m=2n$ then $$5^m-1 = (5^n-1)(5^n+1)$$ so $(5^m-1,5^n+1)=5^n+1$.
The same is true if $m= kn$, $k$ even. So perhaps it is reasonable to believe that if $m\ne kn$, $k$ even then $d=2$. But I'm not sure.

Comment: But $5^m-1$ and $5^n+1$ are both even.

Comment: $\gcd(5^4-1,5^6+1)=26$

Comment: Ahh, that destroys my hypothetis.

Comment: More simply, $\gcd(5^2-1,5^3+1)=6$.

Comment: If $p|m,$  $$(5^p-1,5^m+1)=2$$ and if ,$m/p$ is odd $$(5^m-1,5^p+1)=2$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numeric experiments suggest the following: $m$ is any number, and $n$ is any number **divisible by the same or greater maximum power of $2$ as $m$**. That is, if $m$ is odd, then $n$ is any number; if $m$ is divisible by 2, but not by 4, then $n$ is any even number, and so on.

[image: {m,n}]

Why would that be true?

Well, the necessity of the condition is obvious: if $n=2^k\cdot l,\;2\nmid l$, but $2\mid{m\over2^k}$, then $2^{2^k}+1|2^n+1$, but at the same time $2^{2^k}+1|2^{2^{k+1}}-1\mid2^m-1$.

Now to the point of sufficiency. Suppose my condition is met. Apparently, if $m\leqslant n$, then
$$\gcd(5^m-1,5^n+1)=\gcd(5^m-1,5^n+1-5^{n-m}(5^m-1))=\\=\gcd(5^m-1,5^{n-m}+1)\tag1$$
On the other hand, if $m\geqslant2n$, then
$$\gcd(5^m-1,5^n+1)=\gcd(5^m-1-5^{m-2n}(5^n+1)(5^n-1),5^n+1)=\\=\gcd(5^{m-2n}-1,5^n+1)\tag2$$

This is pretty much like Euclid algorithm, only it limps on one leg, hence we may call it *lame Euclid algorithm*. Because of that, it would not get us all the way down: we'll get stuck at some point where $n<m<2n$. Then our lame Euclid will need crutches to jump over this hole:
$$\gcd(5^m-1,5^n+1)=\gcd(5^m-1-5^{m-n}(5^n+1),5^n+1)=\\
=\gcd(5^{m-n}+1,5^n+1)=\gcd(5^{m-n}+1,5^n+1-5^{2n-m}(5^{m-n}+1)=\\
=\gcd(5^{m-n}+1,5^{2n-m}-1)\tag3$$

See that? $2n-m$ (which is divisible by the same maximum power of 2 as $m$) takes the former role of $m$, while $m-n$ (which is divisible by the same *or maybe greater* power of 2) takes the role of $n$. So we got further down **and the condition is still met**, hence we may continue.

How will all this end? Well, it could have ended on step 2 with $m-2n=0$ and a non-trivial gcd of $5^n+1$, but this is impossible because of the condition. What remains is $n-m=0$ on step 1, which produces the desired $\gcd=2$.

Q.e.d.

Comment: In the case $m-2n=0$: if natural numbers include $0$, which depends on the author, then $5^n+1$ equals $2$ when $n=0$. Then $m=0$, we get a solution.